# Move files to mapped network folder

Tags: ssh, rename, cd-command

I was wanting to know the best or preferred way to move files from one computer to a networked hot folder.  I have looked at `mv` and `cd` but all the references discuss using it locally.  I would need to add this to some already existing scripts.  Also, upon reading I did see SSH File Transfer Protocol and SFTP but everything pointed to a manual process.

Referenced: [here](http://vikashazrati.wordpress.com/2008/02/03/quicktip-transferring-files-between-two-ubuntu-systems/) and [here](http://principialabs.com/beginning-ssh-on-ubuntu/)

EDIT:
and the mapped network folder is windows based if that helps.

Comment: mounted remote filesystems are treated the same as any other local filesystem thanks to VFS.

Comment: @jordanm so basically I need to mount the networked drive as a local drive in ubuntu??

Comment: yes, see `man mount.cifs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On unix systems, the normal way to access files is to [mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28computing%29) the location that contains them. Files thus appear at some point in the directory hierarchy, under the directory that is the *mount point* for the *filesystem* that contains them.

There are several ways to access files on another computer, depending on which protocol is used to authenticate and transfer data. For a “networked folder” that operating systems such as Windows use, the protocol is [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block), usually known in the unix world as [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) (which is the name of the Linux implementation of the protocol). The easiest way to mount a Samba volume is with a GUI: use a menu item like “open network location” (or similar wording) in file browsers such as Nautilus, Konqueror, etc. You can also mount a Samba volume on the command line, with `mount.cifs` (requires root permissions on some platforms) or `gvfs-mount` (from the Gnome virtual filesystem tool suite) or [smbnetfs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smbnetfs/).

You can also access remote files over Samba without mounting using a program dedicated to network transfers, such as `smbclient` (part of the Samba tool suite).

If the remote machine is also a unix machine, it may be easier to set up access with SSH. If you can run commands on the other machine with SSH, you can use `scp` or `sftp` to transfer files. You can also use [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) to mount the remote location over the SFTP protocol. This is a completely different protocol: ssh talks to an ssh server, Samba talks to an SMB server.